# Where can I ask this question about USB ports?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask this question?

> I bought Dell XPS 1340, it has two USB ports. I am currently using
>   one for the keyboard and one for the mouse and I have attached the LED
>   wide-screen to the laptop.
>
> My problem is every time I need to use a USB drive, it is really
>   annoying to not have the mouse because there are only two USB ports.
>   Did anybody face this problem and what can I do? Is there some kind of
>   USB port extender (pardon me for incorrect word) of some sort?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Super User](https://superuser.com/) is the most appropriate community site for computer enthusiasts and power users.

But all you need is a USB hub. That will work just fine. Note that the drive will usually work better if it is plugged in directly, but the mouse and keyboard will show no difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the USB hub answer. I didn't know that.